# If, IIf() and If()

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, iif-function

I recently asked a question about [IIf vs. If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if) and found out that there is another function in VB called **If** which basically does the same thing as **IIf** but is a short-circuit.

Does this **If** function perform better than the **IIf** function?  Does the **If** statement trump the **If** and **IIf** functions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Damn, I really thought you were talking about the operator all along. ;-) Anyway …

> Does this If function perform better than the IIf function?

Definitely. Remember, it's built into the language. Only one of the two conditional arguments has to be evaluated, potentially saving a costly operation.

> Does the If statement trump the If and IIf functions?

I think you can't compare the two because they do different things. If your code semantically performs an assignment you should emphasize this, instead of the decision-making. Use the `If` operator here instead of the statement. This is especially true if you can use it in the initialization of a variable because otherwise the variable will be default initialized, resulting in slower code:

```
Dim result = If(a > 0, Math.Sqrt(a), -1.0)

' versus

Dim result As Double ' Redundant default initialization!
If a > 0 Then
    result = Math.Sqrt(a)
Else
    result = -1
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

One very important distinct between `IIf()` and `If()` is that with `Option Infer On` the later will implicitly cast the results to the same data type in certain cases, as where `IIf` will return `Object`.

Example:

```
    Dim val As Integer = -1
    Dim iifVal As Object, ifVal As Object
    iifVal = IIf(val >= 0, val, Nothing)
    ifVal = If(val >= 0, val, Nothing)
```

Output:
`iifVal`  has value of Nothing and type of Object
`ifVal` has value of 0 and type of Integer, b/c it is implicitly converting Nothing to an Integer.

Comment: Happened last month in my code and I spent an hour debugging to figure this out. This is a drawback of If()