# Expression of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of

Tags: asp.net, telerik, expression, radgrid

I'm getting the below error messagE:

```
Expression of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)'
```

When using the below expression:

```
var expression = "iif({0}.HasValue, String.Format('{0:0.00}%', {0}.Value), 'NA')";
```

This is used for setting Expression property of GridCalculatedColumn which will be added to my GridTableView:

```
var calculatedColumn = new GridCalculatedColumn
            {
                DataFields = dataFields,               
                Expression = expression,                
            };
```

How to convert decimal expression to object expression here?

Thanks

Comment: You should avoid the function `IIF` if possible and replace it with `If(conditon,trueResult,falseResult)`, because with `IIF` both sides are evaluated wheras [If](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) will only evaluate the matching side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if

Comment: If and IIf are keywords for VB.NET. I'm having the expression string in C#. If(conditon,trueResult,falseResult) doesn't exist here.