# Inline If in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my controller, I have and inline If statement:

```
ViewBag.NameSortParam = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder), "Name desc", "")
```

In my view, I can't seem to use inline if:

```
@Code
    If(True, true, true)
End code
```

It says, "If must end with matching End If."  Why can't I use an inline if here?  Thanks.

Comment: yeah this was frustrating. Glad you asked this question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
@Code
    @(If(True, true, true))
End Code
```

Comment: This looks like the answer.  I wonder why it needs the parenthesis?  Thanks for this.

Comment: Probably just a work around to get it working. Alternatively use `IIf(true, "", "")`

Comment: IIF is obsolete, to my knowledge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if

Comment: Also, I believe IIF works differently from IF in that it will execute both true and false statements and will not short circuit like normal if will.

Comment: The main difference for me between IF and IIF is that IF needs a nullable reference type, and IIF just needs an expression which evaluates to a Boolean. Useful when working with Boolean model properties (which arent nullable)

Answer (score 12):

You could use something like this:

```
   @(true? "yes": "no")
```

Comment: I doubt you could use something like this in VB.NET.

Comment: Fix it to be VB.net then

Answer (score 4):

You can do an inline if in vb.net like this:

```
@(If(testExpression, TruePart, FalsePart))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IIf`, you don't need to clutter your code with `@Code` sections:

```
@IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder), "Name desc", "")
```

Comment: Thank you but I believe IIF is obsolete.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if