# Using IIF incorrectly

Tags: vb.net

The button's width is 123. Why doesn't the following change it's width

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    With Me.Button3
        IIf(.Width = 123, .Width = 233, .Width = 150)
    End With
End Sub
```

Does IIF just return a value? i.e if I want to set the button's width property then do I need to use an If structure?

Very little said about Iif in [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does IIF just return a value?

Yes.

> i.e if I want to set the button's width property then do I need to use an If structure?

No, because you can assign the return value to the `Width` property:

```
With Me.Button3 
    .Width = IIf(.Width = 123, 233, 150) 
End With
```

Note that, in current versions of VB.NET, the [If Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) should be used instead of Iif, since it has a variety of advantages (type safety, short-circuiting, etc.). For example, using `If(...)` would allow your code to compile without an additional cast even if you had `Option Strict On` (which you should).

```
With Me.Button3 
    .Width = If(.Width = 123, 233, 150) 
End With
```

Comment: ok - I'm assuming that VB's `Option Strict On` is equivalent functionality to VBA's `Option Explicit` ?

Comment: @whytheq: No, VB's `Option Explicit` is equivalent to VBA's `Option Explicit`. [`Option Strict` is something new:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/zcd4xwzs.aspx) It disallows implicit conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Your code tests `.Width = 123`, then returns the boolean expression `.Width = 233` if true or `.Width = 150` if false, then throws the result away. This is not what you intended. You have three alternatives:

```
' IIf function - not recommended since it is not typesafe and evaluates all arguments.
.Width = IIf(.Width = 123, 233, 150)

' If operator - typesafe and only evaluates arguments as necessary.
.Width = If(.Width = 123, 233, 150)

' If statement - not an expression.
If .Width = 123 Then .Width = 233 Else .Width = 150
```

Comment: ok - but there is no `==` in VB compared to C# so how did the comiler decide that `.Width = 233` was a boolean expression rather than me trying to set a property?

Comment: It depends on context. `<lvalue> = <expression>` is interpreted as the assignment operator, but `=` *inside* an expression is interpreted as the equality operator.

Comment: +1 thanks. So `IIf` is an `expression` whereas `If` is a not an `expression` but an `operator` ?

Comment: I've added to my answer which should clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

Use VB.NEt's If()-statement. It's called 'conditional operator' and exists in many languages. IIf is a VB-specific function and has a different behaviour.
More information here:
[Performance difference between IIf() and If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if)

In both cases, IIf and If just return a value (the IIF ones isn't typed; it's an object that has to be casted). It seems to do the thing you want anyway:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Button3.Width = If(Button3.Width = 123, 233, 150)
End Sub
```