# Substring not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

This seems like a fairly straightforward problem but I keep getting the same exception and I have no idea why.

I can only assume that it has something to do with a misunderstanding of how substring works in VB.NET.

The following code, keeps throwing a ArgumentOutOfRange exception:

```
    <%=Html.Encode(IIf(item.description.Length > 150, item.description.Substring(0, 150), item.description))%>
```

Now what should happen here is, if item.description is over a 150 characters output the first 150 otherwise output the entire string. Problem is it keeps trying to get the sub-string regardless of the length of the result of the if statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `IIF` you evaluate all the expressions - the true as well as the false "branches".

This means that for strings that are under 150 characters long, you still call `item.description.Substring(0, 150)`, causing the error.

Perhaps have an `item.ShortDescription` which only ever return the first 150 characters, using a normal `IF/THEN`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the If(expression,truepart,falsepart) operator instead: the IIF operator attempts to evaluate both the true and false parts whereas the If operator only attempts to evaluate the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

Check this:[IIf() vs. If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if)

```
If(item.description.Length > 150) Then
  item.description.Substring(0, 150) 
Else 
  item.description
End If
```

OR,

```
If(item.description.Length > 150, item.description.Substring(0, 150), item.description)
```