# vb.net if shorthand

Tags: .net, vb.net

is there a way to use shorthand to do something like this?

```
If Not txtBookTitle.Text = String.Empty Then
  objBook.DisplayName = txtBookTitle.Text
End If
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
objBook.DisplayName = If(Not (txtBookTitle.Text = String.Empty), txtBookTitle.Text, objBook.DisplayName)
```

Comment: This is [1 character longer than the original](http://www.lettercount.com/), including the spaces. :)

Comment: don't blame me, blame vb for not implementing a proper ternary operator :P

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the <> operator work on strings?  Why the use of Not?

Comment: i just basically followed the code provided from the question.

Answer (score 8):

Following code is similar to your three line of code:

```
objBook.DisplayName = IIF(String.IsNullorEmpty(txtBookTitle.Text),objBook.DisplayName, txtBookTitle.Text)
```

Comment: i dont recommend using IIF. *Both parameters WILL be evaluated* and that can produce unexpected results for example *if you use functions.* Consider this `IIF(TRUE,JustPrintOK(),ImplodeTheUniverse())`... we are doomed since both functions will be executed regardless of the condition. For VB >= 9 just use `IF` just like your example, it will work without this problem.

Comment: Exactly, one should use `If` and `AndAlso` / `OrElse` instead

Answer (score 7):

There are two version of the if statement shorthand. Either If(expression, true part, false part) or If(expression, false part)

```
objBook.DisplayName = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBookTitle.Text), txtBookTitle.Text)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the shortest version (81 character):

```
If txtBookTitle.Text <> String.Empty Then objBook.DisplayName = txtBookTitle.Text
```

And I would prefer this for debug-ability. Also easily convertible to C#.

Comment: I think it's also clearer than ... If Not txtBookTitle.Text = String.Empty