# If and only if in vb.net 4?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, .net-4.0

IIF seems to be unavailable in .net 4, do we have a replacement?

> IIf(condition = 0, True, False)

Would be a simple if statement a good replacement?

Comment: You spelled "[IF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)" wrong.

Comment: that is not the question

Comment: Then what is your question? I gave you a link to information about vb.net's ternary operator. The only thing left is good ol' `If (True) Than (this) Else (this) End If`. [Maybe this will clarify.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28452/242584)

Comment: `Dim isTrue As Boolean = (condition = 0)` should suffice for your example

Comment: "IIF seems to be unavailable " really?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.iif(v=vs.110).aspx

What error do you have using it?

Comment: What makes you think it is unavailable?  Its part of the `VisualBasic` Namespace - they did not remove it from NET 4.0, but you dont need it anyway, the If Operator works better

Comment: you are all right, i don't know what the problem was, i restarted the visual studio and after a rebuild it all worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second? example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)(VS2015RC) Microsoft is using IIF to illustrate how the If operator is short circuited, so I think IIF is still with us.