# If Condition of VB.NET (IIf) is not equal by C# (?:)

Tags: c#, vb.net, if-statement, iif

The [IIf function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.71).aspx) in VB.NET :

```
IIf(condition As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object
```

exactly is not equal by C# [conditional operator (?:)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) :

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

When I convert some codes from c# to vb.net, I understand that converted codes not work correctly because in vb.net if conditional are evaluated both of the true and false parts before the condition is checked!

For example, C#:

```
public int Divide(int number, int divisor)
{
    var result = (divisor == 0) 
                 ? AlertDivideByZeroException() 
                 : number / divisor;

    return result;
}
```

VB.NET:

```vb
Public Function Divide(number As Int32, divisor As Int32) As Int32

     Dim result = IIf(divisor = 0, _
                  AlertDivideByZeroException(), _
                  number / divisor)

     Return result

End Function
```

Now, my c# codes executed successfully but vb.net codes every times that `divisor` is not equal by zero, runs both of `AlertDivideByZeroException()` and `number / divisor`.

**Why this happens ?**

and

**How and with what do I replace the c# if-conditional operator (?:) in VB.net ?**

Comment: Use [`If(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) instead of `IIf(...)`.

Comment: IIf is a function, there is also a "new" If operator which Mark links to

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but a lot of interesting informations [IIf() vs. If](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Basic, the equality operator is `=`, not `==`. All you need to change is `divisor == 0` to `divisor = 0`.

Also, as Mark said, you should use `If` instead of `IIf`. From the documentation on `If`: `An If operator that is called with three arguments works like an IIf function except that it uses short-circuit evaluation.` Since C# uses short-circuit evaluation, you will want to use `If` for the same functionality in VB.

Comment: I'm sorry, it (==) was a typing mistake that I did edit it.