# Iif not returning value as expected

Tags: vb.net

I use simple if statement and would like to retrieve true or false as Boolean type. I did like this:

```
Iif(text = "something", Convert.ToBoolean(True), Convert.ToBoolean(False))
```

I was trying also this:

```
Iif(text = "something", True, False)
```

For both cases i receive false, but my expression is for sure true. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if

Comment: Use `If` operator instead of old `IIf` function.

The former is a (strongly typed) short circuiting operator which evaluates the second condition only if the first was `False`, the latter evaluates both always.

Comment: You should also show us the value of `text`, maybe it is `Something` or has  leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use the If operator.

```
    Dim someString As String = "something"
    Dim matchSomeString As Boolean = If(someString = "something", True, False)
```

Comment: Why not just `Dim matchSomeString As Boolean = (someString = "something")`?

Comment: Exactly!  How easily I was distracted by the question, not to have seen the obvious.  Thanks @ChrisDunaway

Answer (score 1):

For a simple Boolean value, you can use the comparison result directly

```
dim text as String = "something"
dim result as Boolean

result = (text ="something")
```

Answer (score 0):

AS by the MSDN definition

> **`IIF`** : Returns one of two objects, depending on the evaluation of an expression.

IIF function has a return value that is you need to store the True or false part to some variable.

For eg:

```
Dim _decision As Boolean  =IIf(text = "something", True, False);
```

then convert as

```
Convert.ToBoolean(_decision );
```

Comment: If `_decision` is declared as `Boolean` then calling `Convert.ToBoolean` on a `Boolean` is redundant.

Comment: Yes @ChrisDunaway ... I just want to clear the `IIF` doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

@Tushar Gupta (sorry can't comment yet, but I was about to answer any way)

You don't need to convert your value i juste tested the code below and it perfectly worked (irt was 4 and not 2 at the end of the run)

```
Dim irt = 2
Dim text As String = "abc"
Dim o = IIf(text = "abc", True, False)
If o Then irt = 4
End
```

So I guess you have not stored your return value, or your text value has not exactly the value you expect.

Anyway if you need only true/false I don't see why you are not using a simple if who would be faster.