# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

I got an error on this line that said "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
Me.ShipTextValue.Text = IIf(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderHeader.ShippingText), String.Empty, orderHeader.ShippingText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

However I don't think there is an error on that line, can anyone help me to see whether any error on that line?

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Try `If` rather than `IIf`. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/performance-difference-between-iif-and-if) for more information on the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the old VB6 [`IIF` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) but the [`If`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx), it uses short-circuit evaluation as opposed to `IIF` which evaulates both expressions even if the first already was `True`.

That causes the `NullReferencexception` if  `orderHeader.ShippingText` is `Nothing`.

```
Me.ShipTextValue.Text = If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderHeader.ShippingText), String.Empty, orderHeader.ShippingText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

If you use Visual Basic 14 you can use the [null propagation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
ShipTextValue.Text = orderHeader.ShippingText?.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
```

This will also return `""` if  `orderHeader.ShippingText` is `Nothing`.