# Why doesn't IIf work the same as If/Then/EndIf?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me to understand why If/Then/End If works but IIf doesn't?

I ran my code with this and it works as expected:

```
For Each BtnObj In Padre.Controls
  With BtnObj
    If nullinator(.Tag) = 0 Then
      .Visible = False
    Else
      .Visible = True
    End If
  End With
Next
```

Here's my "nullinator" function:

```
Public Shared Function nullinator(ByVal CheckVal As String) As Integer
    ' Receives a string and returns an integer (zero if Null or Empty or original value)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CheckVal) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return CheckVal
    End If
End Function
```

However, if I run it using this code, nullinator(.Tag) = 0 always equates to be False even if the contents of Tag property is empty. Here's the code:

```
For Each BtnObj In Padre.Controls
    With BtnObj
        IIf(nullinator(.Tag) = 0, .Visible = False, .Visible = True)
    End With
Next
```

Oh yes, the "Padre" variable is the container (parent) object.

Any insights why I'm not having success using IIf would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Returning a string when your function sig wants an Integer is not a great idea.

Comment: Possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/performance-difference-between-iif-and-if , everything in these answers adddess the differences in one form or another... No need to add another one to the books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IIf` returns a value:

```
.Visible = IIf(nullinator(.Tag) = 0, False, True)
```

> Returns one of two objects, depending on the evaluation of an expression.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx

As for why an Object is returned and taken as paraemeters as opposed to any other data type:

> *(an object)* Holds 32-bit (4-byte) addresses that refer to objects. You can assign any reference type (string, array, class, or interface) to an Object variable. **An Object variable can also refer to data of any value type (numeric, Boolean, Char, Date, structure, or enumeration)**. (emphasis my own)

By allowing the function to take **any** value type, there is no need for function overloading.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: now what I cannot understand is why in hell they used a function iif(boolean, object, object) as object, instead of iif(of T)(boolean, T, T) as T

Comment: @Pierre see edit

Comment: @Pierre - Because the `IIF` function predates generics support in VB.  Besides, they replaced it with the `IF` operator which is much better.

Comment: As an aside to this answer, returning `True` or `False` is redundant anyway. You can just use the result of the comparison:  `.Visible = Not (nullinator(.Tag) = 0)`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : I hadn't heard of this IF operator... It does not calculate the useless part? That's great!!

Comment: @Pierre - It's like C#'s conditional operator (?:) and it short circuits (unlike the `IIF` function).  I don't remember precisely when it was introduced.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : thanks, I'll start using it. I had coded a function iff(of T), but obviously both sides were calculated

Answer (score 0):

... because what you think is an assignment is actually  comparison.

The `IIF` function **returns** a value.  So its going to return the result of `.Visible = False` or `.Visible = True`.

To make it work you probably want to remove the comparison and just return `True` or `False`.